# I have a problem with an array namely 0x6dfe78

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a code that tells whether something is a prime number or not. There is an error that I do not understand, namely `0x6dfe78`. Please help me with this error.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double priemgetal,max2 = 0;
    cout << "tiep een getal in: ";
    cin >> priemgetal;
    int  getal = priemgetal;
    int geen_priemgetal[getal]={};

    while(max2 <= 1){
        double komma = priemgetal / getal;

        if ( komma - (int)komma > 0.0 ){
            getal--;
        }else{
            max2++;
            getal--;
        }
        if(getal == 1){
            max2+=2;
        }


    }
    if(priemgetal == 1 || priemgetal == 4){
        cout << priemgetal << " is geen priemgetal";
                    max2+=2;
    }else{
        if(getal == 1){
            cout << priemgetal << " is een priemgetal";
                        max2+=2;
        }else{
            cout << priemgetal << " is geen priemgetal je kan het delen door " << geen_priemgetal ;
                        max2+=2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't see any error demonstrated in your question. I don't know what error code `0x6dfe78` as you mentioned means.

Comment: Variable length arrays, VLA, are not supported by the standard C++.  The `int geen_priemgetal[getal]` is a VLA.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Integer division:  `priemgetal / getal` will always return a integer result.  You should cast numerator or denominator to double.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int  getal = priemgetal;
> int geen_priemgetal[getal]={};
> ```

There is no such thing like Variable Length Arrays (C) in portable C++. Use `std::vector<int>` if you want a container that can hold a variable number of items.

Also, `0x6dfe78` is not an error code but the address of the array you print

> ```
>  cout << priemgetal << " [...] " << /* here-> */ geen_priemgetal /* <- here */;
> ```

Comment: *There is no such thing like Variable Length Arrays (C) in portable C++* -- Please gcc and clang, bite the bullet and turn **off** this option by default.  Too many new programmers use it thinking it's real C++ when it isn't.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I have never worked with a vector. do you want to explain how that works?

Comment: Information on `std::vector` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector